# IIS session timeout occurs randomly - due to error in sending email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, smtp, session-state

So let me explain the situation. Our asp.net mvc application is running on `Windows server 2012 r2` and `IIS 8.5.9600.16384`. Now randomly user session is lost `4/5` times a day although timeout is set to `1000 minutes in process mode`. Now checking the `event viewer` I found 4 errors occurs when when user session is lost (every time below errors repeat when session is lost). Below are the errors...

1.

```
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/7/ROOT

Process ID: 7680

Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException

Message: The operation has timed out.

StackTrace:    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at PDSO.Models.MailClient.<>c__DisplayClass2_1.<SendGMail>b__0(Object o) in 
D:\Development\Projects\YunuscoMRP\YunuscoMRP\Models\Repository\MailClient.cs:line 67
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, 
ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback 
callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at 
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.
IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

2. 

`

```
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage)
   at PDSO.Models.MailClient+<>c__DisplayClass2_1.<SendGMail>b__0(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

`

3.
`

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x52157ba0
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.19724, time stamp: 0x5ec50c3e
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000156e8
Faulting process id: 0x1e00
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8165b6e64aacc
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 38d3cbc4-824f-11ec-8116-000c293f4b2c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

`

4.

```
  An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in w3wp.exe [7680]. 
    Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: Debugger could not be 
    started because no user is logged on.

    Check the documentation index for 'Just-in-time debugging, errors' for more information.
```

I have one class to handle outgoing email. Code is provided below

```
public string SendGMail(string fromEmail, string toEmail, string mailSubject, string mailBody, 
string senderName, string senderPass, string attacmmentLocationPath)
{
try
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
    mail.To.Add(toEmail);
    mail.Subject = mailSubject;
    mail.Body = mailBody;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    //// mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@attacmmentLocationPath));

    //---------------- Enable the block before publish ----------
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com"))
        {
            client.Port = 587;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderName, senderPass);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(mail);
        }
    });
    //-------------------------------------------------------------


    return "Success";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    bool error = new ErrorLogRepository().InsertErrorToDatabase("", "MailClient", "SendGmail", ex.ToString());
    return "Error";
}
}
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with my sending email code or what is causing the `session timeout/iis restart/application pool restart` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a try-catch block to your work item to handle the SMTP client exception and log the error gracefully.  Because the work item executes outside of your SendMail function, the try-catch block in the SendMail function does not handle the exception.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
{
    try
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com"))
        {
            client.Port = 587;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderName, senderPass);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(mail);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        bool error = new ErrorLogRepository().InsertErrorToDatabase("", "MailClient", "SendGmail", ex.ToString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok i will try and give you feedback.

Comment: Your solution does not work. Still same problem it is something to do with `Just-in-time Debugger` error.